# weird jquery show behaviour on firefox

Tags: jquery

I have a simple table and I wish to add rows dynamically to them when some conditions apply.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input class='new' name='test1' value='' /></td>
        <td><input name='test2' value='' /></td>            
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('table').on('keydown', '.new', function () {
if ($(this).val() === '') {
    var newBench = $("<tr><td><input class='new' name='aname' value='' /></td><td><input name='aname' value='' /></td></tr>");
    newBench.hide().appendTo('#dialog table').show('slow');

}
});
```

If you type something in the first input another row is appendend to the table but, when doing so, the td element containing the input where the text was inserted become bigger.
It only happens for the first row and works under IE9.
If I remove the hide() and the show() part, it works as expected.

Here is an example of the code which is not working: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E99pf/1/)

Comment: What if you add `style="display:none;"` to the `<tr>` in `newBench` and remove the `.hide()`? Any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FADE IN WORKING IN IE**

Here you go bro...

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/E99pf/19/)

```
$('table').on('keydown', '.new', function () {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        var newBench = $("<tr><td><input class='new' name='aname' value='' /></td><td><input name='aname' value='' /></td></tr>");

        $(this).closest('tr').after(newBench.hide(function(){$('input', this).fadeIn('slow');}));

    }
});
```

Comment: @FAngel The append was appending to the end of the table, not below the current '<tr>'

Comment: That makes no difference. Here is an example which I got from original code: http://jsfiddle.net/E99pf/15/ And it works too. So, it may be wrong that tr is appened to the end of table, but it has nothing common with previous row being displayed wrong after show

Comment: the actual selector in real code was: newBench.hide().appendTo('#dialog table tbody').show('slow'); and it doesnt work either...

Comment: @FAngel I don't understand your issue?

Comment: IE Won't fadeIn() a <tr><td> element it seems...with that being said, we need to fade in only the added inputs :)

Comment: @VIDesignz - I'm just saying that table appearance is broken not because of a place where new tr is placed. Looks like fadeIn just set correct `display` if it works with TR (when `.show("slow")` sets a wrong `display:block`). Plus you have an interesting usage of fadeIn which is applied before item is appended (and even not hidden ), but works correctly (as you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/E99pf/15/) - which was new and unexpected to me )

Comment: I get what your saying about the table structure...not going to spend too much time worrying about that.  As far as the append, it does happen first '.after()' then it '.hides()' when the hide completes, the callback is to fade in the input and the tr, the tr just 'shows' since it won't fade in, while the input fades in. Make sense? :)

Answer (score 1):

That is somehow related to `display:block` which is set by `.show()` Not sure how that could be fixed. I've updated code to this and got it working in FF:

```
$('table').on('keydown', '.new', function () {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {            
        var newBench = $("<tr><td><input class='new' name='aname' value='' /></td><td><input name='aname' value='' /></td></tr>");
        newBench.hide().appendTo('#dialog table').css('display', 'table-row');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E99pf/6/

Not sure how it could be shown slowly. Code below does not work for sure:

```
newBench.hide().appendTo('#dialog table').show('slow', function(){$(this).css('display', 'table-row')});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E99pf/5/